# ImageView scale up animation cuts off image

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-animation

In my app I would like to animate an icon expanding to about 120% of its size. The problem is that when I do this the contents of the ImageView get cut off. Is there anyway to grow it so that this doesn't happen?

[image]

The calling of the animation:

```
Animation sgAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.highlight);
charm.startAnimation(sgAnimation);
```

The animation itself:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillBefore="true"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
android:shareInterpolator="true" >

<scale
    android:duration="100"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toXScale="1.5"
    android:toYScale="1.5" />
</set>
```

And the layout section pertaining to the imageview:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/over_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     >        
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/charms_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/charm_phone"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:alpha=".75"
        android:contentDescription="@string/account_image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_phone_white_24dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/charm_lock"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/account_image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_qs_lock_screen_off" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/charm_camera"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:alpha=".75"
        android:contentDescription="@string/account_image_description"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_camera_white_24dp" />
```

Note: I have already tried replacing 24dp with wrap_content, but that didn't work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I ended up adding padding to the imageview and increasing the size of the imageview by the extra padding. This way when it was animated, it animated into the padding space and was not cropped.

Answer (score 17):

I would try using

```
android:clipChildren="false"
android:clipToPadding="false"
```

In your imageView container and in your imageview

Comment: Can you post your layouts please?

Comment: added container and view itself to original post

Comment: So you tried and then removed the property I suggested because they don't work right?

Comment: yes I tried adding two properties you suggested to both the relativelayout and the imageview

Comment: is there another layout containing the relative layout or this is the root?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58057/discussion-between-bionicsheep-and-alexbalo).

Comment: Thanks. I've added clipToPadding to the container and it works!

Comment: Worked well for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could have achieved the expected result by giving ImageView's parent layout height according to the scaling animation.

In your case you are trying to animate a ImageView which is 24dp in width and height. Therefore you will need a 36dp room for the ImageView to animate properly. Since you gave layout width as match_parent, your image didn't cut from left and right sides, but wrap content for the height is not going to work.

Considering one image:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="36dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="24dp"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:src="@drawable/src_image"/>

<RelativeLayout/>
```